# C standard header file for non-printable/control character constants

Tags: c, ascii

So, whenever I need to reference certain ASCII control characters I find myself doing junk like this:

```
#define STX 2
#define ETX 3
```

Is there some C header file found in most development environments (LINUX probably) that define these constants for me so that I don't have to use magic numbers or define them all the time?  Something like `<stdint.h>.`

I've been writing C code for 35 years and I've never come across such a header file.

Comment: Well, if you never came across such a header file (I didn't, too), it probably does not exist.

Comment: `#define 2 STX` how does that work? Did you mean `#define STX 2` ?

Comment: Yes, जलजनक they were swapped.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can do for you off the top of my head:

#### 1. Using the Linux Documentation Project's manpage source

This file is likely to be present somewhere on your machine; the path I used is where you'll find it on a Debian/Ubuntu install. The list only includes C0 codes, but maybe that's good enough:

```
$ gunzip -c /usr/share/man/man7/ascii.7.gz |
>   awk '$1~/0[0-3][0-7]/{printf "#define C0_%-3s %2d\n", $4, $2}'
#define C0_NUL  0
#define C0_SOH  1
#define C0_STX  2
#define C0_ETX  3
#define C0_EOT  4
#define C0_ENQ  5
#define C0_ACK  6
#define C0_BEL  7
#define C0_BS   8
#define C0_HT   9
#define C0_LF  10
#define C0_VT  11
#define C0_FF  12
#define C0_CR  13
#define C0_SO  14
#define C0_SI  15
#define C0_DLE 16
#define C0_DC1 17
#define C0_DC2 18
#define C0_DC3 19
#define C0_DC4 20
#define C0_NAK 21
#define C0_SYN 22
#define C0_ETB 23
#define C0_CAN 24
#define C0_EM  25
#define C0_SUB 26
#define C0_ESC 27
#define C0_FS  28
#define C0_GS  29
#define C0_RS  30
#define C0_US  31
```

#### 2. Using the Unicode Character Database.

This includes a lot more, with lots of Unicode control characters, some of them in the astral plane, although obviously you can filter it. It also includes some extra abbreviation names. The file `NamedAliases.txt` can be downloaded from https://www.unicode.org/Public/14.0.0/ucd/NameAliases.txt or you can grab the entire UCD as a zipped archive at https://www.unicode.org/Public/zipped/14.0.0/

I truncated the output at 60 lines; the entire list is 353 lines.

```sh
awk -F\; '$3=="abbreviation"
            {printf "#define CTL_%-8s 0x%s\n", $2, $1}' \ 
      UCD/NameAliases.txt
#define CTL_NUL      0x0000
#define CTL_SOH      0x0001
#define CTL_STX      0x0002
#define CTL_ETX      0x0003
#define CTL_EOT      0x0004
#define CTL_ENQ      0x0005
#define CTL_ACK      0x0006
#define CTL_BEL      0x0007
#define CTL_BS       0x0008
#define CTL_HT       0x0009
#define CTL_TAB      0x0009
#define CTL_LF       0x000A
#define CTL_NL       0x000A
#define CTL_EOL      0x000A
#define CTL_VT       0x000B
#define CTL_FF       0x000C
#define CTL_CR       0x000D
#define CTL_SO       0x000E
#define CTL_SI       0x000F
#define CTL_DLE      0x0010
#define CTL_DC1      0x0011
#define CTL_DC2      0x0012
#define CTL_DC3      0x0013
#define CTL_DC4      0x0014
#define CTL_NAK      0x0015
#define CTL_SYN      0x0016
#define CTL_ETB      0x0017
#define CTL_CAN      0x0018
#define CTL_EOM      0x0019
#define CTL_SUB      0x001A
#define CTL_ESC      0x001B
#define CTL_FS       0x001C
#define CTL_GS       0x001D
#define CTL_RS       0x001E
#define CTL_US       0x001F
#define CTL_SP       0x0020
#define CTL_DEL      0x007F
#define CTL_PAD      0x0080
#define CTL_HOP      0x0081
#define CTL_BPH      0x0082
#define CTL_NBH      0x0083
#define CTL_IND      0x0084
#define CTL_NEL      0x0085
#define CTL_SSA      0x0086
#define CTL_ESA      0x0087
#define CTL_HTS      0x0088
#define CTL_HTJ      0x0089
#define CTL_VTS      0x008A
#define CTL_PLD      0x008B
#define CTL_PLU      0x008C
#define CTL_RI       0x008D
#define CTL_SS2      0x008E
#define CTL_SS3      0x008F
#define CTL_DCS      0x0090
#define CTL_PU1      0x0091
#define CTL_PU2      0x0092
#define CTL_STS      0x0093
#define CTL_CCH      0x0094
#define CTL_MW       0x0095
#define CTL_SPA      0x0096
...
```